# How to change the boolean value on the report to display as yes / no instead of true /false

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

In SSRS , the boolean field from a sharepoint list is being displayed as true or False , I would liek that to be displayed as Yes or NO in the field. How do I do this ?

Comment: On the textbox in the report, create an expression `IIF(field.value = True, "Yes", "No")`

Comment: I am using a lookup function to pull the data into the report field =LOOKUP(Fields!TXT.Value, Fields!TXT.Value, Fields!FUN.Value, "SPList") So , how do I format this field here  Fields!FUN.Value

Comment: encapsulate your expression with an IIF. For example =IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!TXT.Value, Fields!TXT.Value, Fields!FUN.Value, "SPList") = True , "Yes" , "No")

Comment: supersimmer-44 , thank u

Comment: This should be added as an answer so it can be marked as accepted. It will stop people looking for an answer from ignoring this question as it looks unanswered and stop people wanting to answer questions, finding this because it's 'unanswered'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encapsulate your expression with an IIF. For example =IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!TXT.Value, Fields!TXT.Value, Fields!FUN.Value, "SPList") = True , "Yes" , "No") – SuperSimmer 44 21 hours ago